# How can I change icon on AJax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an anchor tag with an icon inside that I want to change it on click.
So, using Ajax I tried as below:

**HTML**

```
<a id="#pl-esong234" class="social-button-song" title="Add in playlist" onclick="addInPlaylistSongs(234, 1)">
  <i class="ion-plus all-btn-icon"></i>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
function addInPlaylistSongs(track, id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl+"/requests/manage_playlists.php",
        data: "id="+track+"&playlist="+id+"&type=4&token_id="+token_id, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#pl-esong'+track).append('<i class="ion-checkmark all-btn-icon"></i>');
        }
    });
}
```

I tried also:

```
//2nd try
$('#pl-esong'+track+' i').after('<i class="ion-checkmark all-btn-icon"></i>').remove();

//3rd try
$('#pl-esong'+track+' i').after(html).remove();

//4th try
$('#pl-esong'+track+' i').replaceWith(html);
```

I tried to console log on success and everything is correct, the html response is `<i class="ion-checkmark all-btn-icon"></i>` and the select item is `#pl-esong234`.

Why I'm not able to change the icon inside my anchor element?

Comment: $('#pl-esong'+track).html('<i class="ion-checkmark all-btn-icon"></i>');

Comment: this is the simple code why you put i after track, just use html() method to change inside code, you are going to change the html of "A" tag not i tag.

Comment: @Prateik I tried many things only because I have had an oversight with `id="#pl-esong234"`

Comment: i don't understand, can you explain me so i can make sure about your problem.

Comment: @Prateik I didn't see the hashtag here `<a id="#pl-esong234"... `

Comment: okay, right so the hashtag is not required here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `hash` from the id. It is using by the selectors to find the matched tag.

`#` - used to find by id.
`.` - user to find by class

```
<a id="pl-esong234" class="social-button-song" title="Add in playlist" onclick="addInPlaylistSongs(234, 1)">
  <i class="ion-plus all-btn-icon"></i>
</a>
```

and call `html()`.

```
$('#pl-esong'+track+' i').html('<i class="ion-checkmark all-btn-icon"></i>');
```

Comment: I become crazy for this...incredible how I miss this

Comment: @suren can't we remove i when we are changing the whole html, i think i tag will place the same code in another i tag.

Comment: Yes you are right.In his case we can only change the class of the `i` element. But if he doesn't know the names of the classes, so instead of iterating over the classes, we can just replace it